# Use values recieved from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to make a little weather station that recieves 4 values.
This is the data I get when reading from the serial port: [image]

And I already managed to split it,so I only get the values.
This looks like this: [image]

Now I'ld like to do something with those values (Putting them in graphs, save as CSV, Add comma for temperature, go from hexadecimal to decimal for the pressure,.. ) but I have no idea how I can work with them.

I Was thinking of putting them in an array (undifined rows x 4 columns) or list, but I've no idea how to do that.
Or maybe there is an eaier solution that I have not thinked about.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace WeatherStation
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort port;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8);
            port.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
            port.Open();

        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }

    }
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

            string data = sp.ReadLine();

            string[] ret = data.Split(':');


            if (data != String.Empty)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() => txtBoxData.AppendText(ret[1] + '\t')))
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exc) //!!
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.Close();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBoxData.Clear();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"test.cvs");
            writer.Write(txtBoxData.Text);
            writer.Close();
        }

        catch (IOException exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is your main question? sending Data to Excel or something else?

Comment: Well, my main goal is to use this data and plot them in 4 auto updated graphs (With the help of an interface)

Comment: User Control not an interface ..  sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could store the tag, value, and timestamp as a row in a file. Comma-delimited would probably work.

```
if (data != String.Empty)
{
    string[] ret = data.Split(':');
    string text = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss},{1},{2}", DateTime.Now, ret[0], ret[1]);
    File.AppendAllText(@"c:\MyFile.csv", text);
}
```

The above code will add one line per event, to a file named "MyFile.csv". The first column will have the date and time, the second will have the metric type, and the third will have the value.

Once you have added enough lines to the file, you can open it in Excel and make it into a useful table by using the pivot table feature, then create a graph of the data. Or you could load the data into a database and run queries against it.